# Discord.py device temperature command

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, discord, discord.py

I wanted to make a command for my bot that help me check my Raspberry Pi temperature. I tried to make a command, and `ctx.send(os.system('vcgencmd measure_temp'))` but it sends "0". I tried just `ctx.send(vcgencmd measure_temp)` but it still not works, can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system` returns the return code of the command. Use `subprocess.run` instead to get stdout(I'm assuming that's where vsgencmd outputs):

```
await ctx.send(subprocess.run(["vcgencmd", "measure_temp"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode("utf-8").strip())
```

The `.decode("utf-8")` converts the stdout from bytes to a str and strip drops the trailing newline.

Comment: Thanks! It works! But instead of `temp=*something*` it sends `b"temp=43.0'C\n"` can you tell me how to delete this `b"` and `\n"`?

Comment: @MaciejkaG should be fixed.